# Docker build указать путь для Dockerfile

Tags: docker

Нужно создать образ с определенным тегом, и прописать путь до Dockerfile, но вот так:

```
docker build -t nginx:latest --file ./deploying/Docker/Dockerfile
```

или так

```
docker build -t nginx:latest -f ./deploying/Docker/Dockerfile
```

выдает ошибку:

```
"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker build --help'.
```

Comment: Ну а контекст кто задавать будет?

Comment: @AlexeyTen можете написать в ответе рабочий вариант?

Comment: Ну что-нибудь типа `docker build -t nginx:latest -f ./deploying/Docker/Dockerfile ./deploying/Docker`

Comment: @AlexeyTen не понимаю зачем ему указывать еще и директорию, но ваш вариант сработал. Спасибо. Оформите как ответ - подниму вам карму.

Comment: Директорию нужно указывать, так как там могут лежать и другие файлы помимо `Dockerfile`. Та же директива `COPY`, к примеру, берёт файлы именно из указанной директории.